# What is the best way to float a button next to a select box with CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, struts2

I have the `button` floating right next to the `select`, and have also added a top `margin` but wanted to see if there was a better way to handle what I'm trying to achieve.

> Please reference the screen shot below.

Here is the `html` for how I have done this already. Is there a better way to achieve this than using `margin` top? Somebody had made a change and it broke my `32px` `margin` I had.

I have gone through similar posts on here but couldn't seem to get this button to align properly with solutions given in previous posts.

Thanks.

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <s:select list="dnldrepoEmpGroupList" listKey="dnldrepoEmpGroupNo" listValue="folderName" name="entity.dnldrepoEmpGroup.dnldrepoEmpGroupNo" requiredLabel="true" label="Grouping" headerValue="--Select One--" headerKey="" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button name="addGroupingName" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:32px;">Add</button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

[image]

Here is all of the html for this

```
<div id="ajaxResult">
<div id="downloadResult">
    <div id="actionMessage">
        <s:actionmessage cssClass="actionMessage" />
        <s:actionerror cssClass="actionMessage ui-state-error" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="downloadTableResult">
        <s:hidden name="entity.dnldrepoNo" />
        <s:hidden name="entity.dwnldrepoType" />
        <s:hidden name="entity.uploadUser.userNo" />
        <s:hidden name="entity.dwnldrepoUploaddt"  />
        <s:set var="downloadType"
                       value="#{'Employer Download':'Employer Download', 'Temp Download':'Temp Download'}" />
        <s:textfield name="entity.dwnldrepoDisplayname"
                                 label="Display Name"
                                 requiredLabel="true"/>
        <s:if test="%{entity.dwnldrepoType == 'Temp Download'}">
            <s:textarea name="entity.dnldrepolookups"
                                    label="Email"
                                    requiredLabel="true"/>
        </s:if>
        <s:if test="%{entity.dwnldrepoType == 'Employer Download'}">
            <s:textfield data-display="%{entity.dnldrepoEmpGroup.employer.employerName}"  name="entity.dnldrepoEmpGroup.employer.employerNo" id="clientKeyAutoComplete" label="Employer" />
            <div class="input-group">
                <s:select list="dnldrepoEmpGroupList" listKey="dnldrepoEmpGroupNo" listValue="folderName" name="entity.dnldrepoEmpGroup.dnldrepoEmpGroupNo" requiredLabel="true" label="Grouping" headerValue="--Select One--" headerKey="" />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button name="addGroupingName" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </s:if>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 rowData">
        <div class="text-danger">
            <s:property value="%{entity.dwnldrepoPointer}" />
        </div>
        <s:hidden name="entity.dwnldrepoPointer" />
        <s:file name="entity.planFile" label="File Upload" />
        <s:textfield name="entity.dwnldrepoRetain"
                                   label="Retain Hours"
                                   requiredLabel="true"
                                   helpText="Enter 0 hours to retain forever"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what happens when I used the Flexbox solution as well as the solution from the Bootstrap 4 docs.

[image]

Also, to note, we're using Struts in this project and these Struts inputs are producing the following which I have suspicion may be the reason why I cannot get the solutions posted to work. Here is a snipped of what Struts produces when rendering the document.

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class=" control-label" for="entity_dnldrepoEmpGroup_dnldrepoEmpGroupNo">Grouping            

        <i class="fa fa-asterisk required" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <div class=" controls">
        <select name="entity.dnldrepoEmpGroup.dnldrepoEmpGroupNo" id="entity_dnldrepoEmpGroup_dnldrepoEmpGroupNo" class="form-control">
            <option value="">--Select One--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a screen shot I just took that shows the add button seems to be aligning to the top of the label. This is why I had originally pushed it down with margin-top but was wondering if there was a better solution to this madness to align to the top of the input field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being the label the Struts 2 Bootstrap plugin was rending which was aligning the button to the top of the label instead of the input field.  Here's the solution I came up with if anybody encounters this with the plugin. This kind of convoluted things a bit with my originally questions because I didn't really realize this at the time.

The label needs to be omitted from the Struts select or input field and moved to the top outside of the input group to get this working. I have also attached another screen shot of this implementation.

Struts 2 Twitter Bootstrap plugin - http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-bootstrap-showcase/advanced.action

I want to add that the answers provided in this thread would have been correct if it wasn't for this unique situation. Thank you all for your contributions to my problem.

[image]

```
                      <label>Grouping</label>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <s:select list="dnldrepoEmpGroupList" listKey="dnldrepoEmpGroupNo" listValue="folderName" name="entity.dnldrepoEmpGroup.dnldrepoEmpGroupNo" requiredLabel="true" headerValue="--Select One--" headerKey="" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button name="addGroupingName" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Best way is use `input-group` like mention here in [Bootstrap DOC](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox:

```css
.input-group{
    display: flex;
    max-width: 60%;
    margin: 2em;
}

.input-group input{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.input-group button{
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button name="addGroupingName" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added this css but my button is still above the select box. Please reference what this looks like on my end with this implemented. I think something may be wrong with my screen layout. I have added more information to my original question to reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"There could be many ways to do a thing:"

This solution is from Bootstrap:

[Click to see Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrx83.png)

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```